# How to detect 2D line on line collision?

Tags: mathematics, actionscript-3, linear-algebra

I'm a flash actionscript game developer who is a bit backward with mathematics, though I find physics both interesting and cool.

For reference this is a similar game to the one I'm making: [Untangled flash game](http://www.addictinggames.com/puzzle-games/untangle.jsp)

I have made this untangled game almost to full completion of logic. But, when two lines intersect, I need those intersected or 'tangled' lines to show a different color; red.

It would be really kind of you people if you could suggest an algorithm for detecting **line segment** collisions. 
I'm basically a person who likes to think 'visually' than 'arithmetically' :)

Edit: I'd like to add a few diagrams to make convey the idea more clearly

[image: no intersection]
[image: no intersection]
[image: intersection]
[image: no intersection]

P.S I'm trying to make a function as

```
private function isIntersecting(A:Point, B:Point, C:Point, D:Point):Boolean
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a disappointingly non-visual explanation of the problem, but it is an algorithm and it does make sense if you can bring yourself to read their maths: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/ It may be heavy if your vector maths is weak. I understand -- I also prefer visual explanations. I'll try to find time later to doodle this, but if someone at all artistically inclined sees this link and has time before I do, get to it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use the following method which is pretty much just an implementation of [this algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20060911055655/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/%7Epbourke/geometry/lineline2d/). It's in C# but translating it to ActionScript should be trivial.

```cs
bool IsIntersecting(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d)
{
    float denominator = ((b.X - a.X) * (d.Y - c.Y)) - ((b.Y - a.Y) * (d.X - c.X));
    float numerator1 = ((a.Y - c.Y) * (d.X - c.X)) - ((a.X - c.X) * (d.Y - c.Y));
    float numerator2 = ((a.Y - c.Y) * (b.X - a.X)) - ((a.X - c.X) * (b.Y - a.Y));

    // Detect coincident lines (has a problem, read below)
    if (denominator == 0) return numerator1 == 0 && numerator2 == 0;
    
    float r = numerator1 / denominator;
    float s = numerator2 / denominator;

    return (r >= 0 && r <= 1) && (s >= 0 && s <= 1);
}
```

There's a subtle problem with the algorithm though, which is the case in which two lines are coincident but don't overlap. The algorithm still returns an intersectioin in that case. If you care about that case, I believe [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255848/1086334) has a more complex version that addresses it.

**Edit**

> I did not get a result from this algorithm, sorry !

That's strange, I've tested it and it's working for me except for that single case I described above. Using the exact same version I posted above I got these results when I took it for a test drive:

[image]

Comment: I did not get a result from this algorithm, sorry !

Comment: @Vish What problem did you have? I tested this exact copy of the algorithm before posting and it worked flawlessly except for the single case described.

Comment: Then , let me try again, I might have mixed up some math in it. I'll let you know soon. Thanks a ton ,nyways :)

Comment: @DavidGouveia I think you could check if lines are coincident/parallel with something like: `ab.Y / ab.X == cd.Y / cd.X`, where `ab` is the delta between `a` and `b` and `cd` the delta between `c` and `d`. If that condition is met, simply return false.

Comment: @bummzack That's not really the problem, because checking for parallelism and coincidence is *already* handled by the algorithm, i.e. when the denominator is 0 both lines are parallel, and when both numerators are also 0 then the lines are coincident. The problem is determining whether two coincident lines segments are *intersecting* or not, at least using *this* algorithm which relies on checking if the results of the division falls within the [0-1] range, but 0/0 is indeterminate. The solution I linked is more complex, and handles that particular case separately with another algorithm.

Comment: I got the desired result from you algorithm , thanks @DavidGouveia.

Comment: Well, but now I have another problem :) ! I need to make the intersected lines with red color and green. The intersection works fine. But as I've understood now, (not mathematically though) that a simple if-else won't work as for putting red and green lines for intersected and non-intersected lines. The node i am dragging has both a left and right line . So, something's gone wrong somewhere while changing the color of non-intersected lines back to green. I guess I need another condition too. Hmmm, anyways thanks a ton, I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: As of July 2018, the link for the algorithm description needs to be updated to http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/   .  That link comes with a thorough algorithm description along with working code in several languages...

Answer (score 5):

Without Divisions! So no problem with precision nor by division by zero.

Line segment 1 is A to B
Line segment 2 is C to D

A line is a never ending line, the line segment is a defined part of that line.

Check if the two bounding boxes intersect : if no intersection -> No Cross! (calculation done, return false)

Check if line seg 1 straddles line seg  2 and if line seg 2 straddles line seg 1 (ie. line Segment 1 is on both sides of Line defined by the line Segment 2).

This can be made by translating all points by -A (ie. you move the 2 lines so A is in origo (0,0))

Then you check if point C and D is on different sides of the line defined by 0,0 to B

```
//Cross Product (hope I got it right here)
float fC= (B.x*C.y) - (B.y*C.x); //<0 == to the left, >0 == to the right
float fD= (B.x*D.y) - (B.y*D.x);

if( (fc<0) && (fd<0)) //both to the left  -> No Cross!
if( (fc>0) && (fd>0)) //both to the right -> No Cross!
```

If you haven't already got a "No Cross" then continue using not A,B versus C,D but C,D versus A,B (same calcs, just swap A and C, B and D), if there are no "No Cross!" then you have an intersection!

I searched for the exact calculations for the cross product and found [This blog post](http://www.keymarkenterprises.com/_blog/Keymark_Blog/post/Mathematics_of_Software_for_Structural_Engineering_/) that explains the method too.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not quite good with vector maths, I implemented this algorithm as such, but got no result, sorry !

Comment: It should work so maybe if you can show us your code we can help you out there?

Comment: Nice! however the link is broken

Comment: Is there something you can add to this to get the point of intersection?

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say, I needed it for my Gamemaker Studio game and it works well:

```
///scr_line_collision(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)

var denominator= ((argument2 - argument0) * (argument7 - argument5)) - ((argument3 - argument1) * (argument6 - argument4));
var numerator1 = ((argument1 - argument5) * (argument6 - argument4)) - ((argument0 - argument4) * (argument7 - argument5));
var numerator2 = ((argument1 - argument5) * (argument2 - argument0)) - ((argument0 - argument4) * (argument3 - argument1));

// Detect coincident lines
if (denominator == 0) {return (numerator1 == 0 && numerator2 == 0)}

var r = numerator1 / denominator;
var s = numerator2 / denominator;

return ((r >= 0 && r <= 1) && (s >= 0 && s <= 1));
```

Comment: I think this answer could really improve if you explained what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer gave a wrong answer in this case:

```
x1 = 0;
y1 = 0;
x2 = 10;
y2 = 10;

x3 = 10.1;
y3 = 10.1;
x4 = 15;
y4 = 15;
```

These lines obviously don't intersect, but according to the function in the "correct answer" the lines do intersect.

This is what I use:

```
function do_lines_intersect(px1,py1,px2,py2,px3,py3,px4,py4) {
  var ua = 0.0;
  var ub = 0.0;
  var ud = (py4 - py3) * (px2 - px1) - (px4 - px3) * (py2 - py1);


  if (ud != 0) {
    ua = ((px4 - px3) * (py1 - py3) - (py4 - py3) * (px1 - px3)) / ud;
    ub = ((px2 - px1) * (py1 - py3) - (py2 - py1) * (px1 - px3)) / ud;
        if (ua < 0.0 || ua > 1.0 || ub < 0.0 || ub > 1.0) ua = 0.0;
  }

  return ua;
}
```

returns 0 = the lines do not intersect

returns > 0 = the lines intersect

**Update to answer the question:**

I did not create this code myself. It is over 5 years old and I don't know what the original source is. But..

I think the return value is the relative position of the first line where they cross (to explain it badly). To calculate the point of intersection you could probably use lerp like this:

```
l = do_lines_intersect(...)
if (l > 0) {
    intersect_pos_x = l * (px2-px1);
    intersect_pos_y = l * (py2-py1);
} else {
    // lines do not cross
}
```

(I DID NOT TEST THIS)

Comment: Is there a version of this that returns the point of intersection?